# "Many meanings" in French

Tags: expressions

I asked on a learning site the French translation for "many meanings."

I was offered the version of "plusieurs significations."

In the body of my question, I had given as a possible translation the phrase "beaucoup de sens."

Knowing that *[sens](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/meaning)* is both *meaning* and *meaning**s***, was not my translation also correct?

Comment: Is your question about the difference in meaning between *sens* & *signification* (on which case you need to give the context where you want to use the word) about the use of *plusieurs* (several) vs *beaucoup* (many/a lot) or about *beaucoup de sens* which can either mean "a lot of meaning" or "a lot of meanings". A lot of people will use *sens* and *signification* as synonyms, but they aren't synonyms.

Comment: your translation was also correct, and even better imho, since there is no confusion between sens/signification. _It just makes more sense_, if I can say ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your translation is indeed correct as such, but might be misinterpreted, mainly because `sens` is written and pronounced the same way singular or plural. Out of any context, `beaucoup de sens` might mean `a lot of sense`.

I would indeed use `plusieurs significations`, or `différentes significations` but if you want to use your locution, I would then say:

> ... beaucoup de sens différents.

The `différents` here implies plural form of `sens`, translating to `meanings` instead of `meaning`.

Comment: Could I have also used _maintes sens_? Would this have been old-fashioned?

Comment: Well, technically you could, but `maintes` is indeed really outdated and I wouldn't use it outside a very formal context.

Comment: Just checking to make sure I can.

Comment: `maintes significations` seems better than `maintes sens`.

Comment: If you are talking about the _different meanings_ of a _word_, you can use `plusieurs acceptions`.
The French noun `acception` refers to a specific meaning of a word.

Comment: How about just `plusieurs sens` instead of `beaucoup de sens`?

Comment: Just to make it clear, a non-negligible part of today's French speakers would not even understand `maintes`. Besides, `maintes sens` is wrong, because `mainte` is feminine. The masculine is `maint`, so `maints sens` would be okay. In addition, `maint`/`mainte` is used for uncountable nouns, while `maints`/`maintes` is used for countable nouns.

Comment: @User26328 - *Maintes sens* is grammatically incorrect, because *maintes* is feminine whereas *sens* is masculine. *Maints sens* would be grammatically correct.

Comment: @ChrisW > I just wanted to use the same wording as the OP but indeed plusieurs seems more effective in this case

Answer (score 8):

You could also say: « X a de nombreux sens », « X a des sens multiples » or « X a bien des sens ». It is difficult to translate an expression without knowing the rest of the sentence.